# Calculate distance based on coordinates

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My task is to calculate the total length of roads from city. I'm using OSM data. After importing it to the database I have the following structure (This seemed logic to me but I can change if you think there is a better way):

- There is a root node for each rode segment (way tag in OSM XML) that holds an ID and a type (I have other types as well but they are irrelevant now)
- To the root node is connected to the first node of the road with a relation 'defines'
- Every node is connected to the next one with a relation called 'connected' that has a property 'entity_id' which is the root nodes id. (One node can appear in more road segments, for example intersections, so I'm trying to avoid circles with this property.

I'm pretty new to Neo4J. I only have experience in SQL databases but based on that I feel like even if my approach was working, it would loose the advantage of the query language (referring to speed).

So here is what I have so far, but it is not even close. It outputs the same number (wrong number) a lot of times instead of one total. I'm pretty sure I did not get the whole idea of **with** but can't figure out what would be the solution:

```
CREATE (t:Tmp {total:0})
with t
MATCH (e:Entity {type:'road'})
with collect(e) as es, t
    unwind es as entity
        match p = ()-[r:connected {entity_id:entity.int_id}]->()
        with entity, p,t 
        SET entity.lng = 0
        with entity, p, t
        unwind nodes(p) as nd
            with  t,nd,point({longitude:toFloat(nd.lon), latitude: toFloat(nd.lat)}) as point1, entity
                SET entity.lng = entity.lng + distance(entity.p, point1)
            with  t,nd,point({longitude:toFloat(nd.lon), latitude: toFloat(nd.lat)}) as point1, entity
                SET entity.p = point1
        with entity, t
        SET t.total = t.total + entity.lng
return t.total
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is returning the current `t.total` result per node, instead of an overall total value. And it seems to be incorrectly calculating a distance for the first node in a segment (the first node should have a 0 distance).  It is also very inefficient. For example, it does not bother to leverage the `defines` relationship. In a neo4j query, it is vitally important to use the power of relationships to avoid scanning through a lot of irrelevant data.

In addition, there is no mention of a particular "city". Your query is for all `Entity` nodes. If your DB only contains `Entity` nodes for a single city, then that is OK. Otherwise, you will need to modify the query to only match `Entity` nodes for a specific city.

The following query may do what you want (going simply by what I gleaned from your question, and assuming your DB only has data for a single city), using the `defines` relationship to efficiently match the `start` node for each `Entity` segment, and using that `start` node to efficiently find the `connected` nodes of interest:

```
MATCH (entity:Entity {type:'road'})-[:defines]->(start)
MATCH p=(start)-[:connected* {entity_id:entity.id}]->(end)
WHERE NOT EXISTS((end)-[:connected {entity_id:entity.id}]->())
SET entity.lng = 0
SET entity.p = point({longitude:toFloat(start.lon), latitude: toFloat(start.lat)})
WITH entity, p
UNWIND TAIL(NODES(p)) AS nd
WITH point({longitude:toFloat(nd.lon), latitude: toFloat(nd.lat)}) as pt, entity
SET entity.lng = entity.lng + distance(entity.p, pt)
SET entity.p = pt
RETURN SUM(entity.lng) AS total
```

The [aggregating function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/functions/aggregating/) `SUM()` is used to return the total `lng` for all entities. The `t` node is not needed. The `WHERE` clause only matches paths that comprise complete segments. This query also initializes `entity.p` to the `point` of the `start` node, and `UNWINDS` the nodes after the `start` node.

If there are many `Entity` nodes with `type` values other than "road", you may also want to create an [index](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/) on `:Entity(type)`.

Comment: Yes, in my case it is save to assume that there is only one city in the database. Thanks :)

Comment: Hey, I've just realised there is a problem. The code calculates the distance for each entity correctly but if you remove the sum aggregate function you will notice that the for every entity is returned n times where n is the number of nodes in the path minus one. Do you have any idea?

Comment: You don't actually have a "problem" if the query gives you the right result, do you? Unfortunately, your comment is missing some words (after "notice that the"), so I don't know what you are actually asking. But take look at `TAIL(NODES(p))` -- you might find that helpful.

Comment: Oh sorry about that :) “the distance is returned n times”. Actually  I tought the resutls were good but because of What I said above they were not. So for example one specific etity’s lenght is 168 but If I add a condition for id in the First match and remove the sum I get 4 rows of 168. I’m assuming something like the return is executed for each iteration of the unwind but I’m not sure Why is it n times the correct distance instead of a bunch of partial results then the correct distance.